# how to read and overwrite part of batch file in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a batch file look like something below:

```
.....
set ARGS=%ARGS% /startDate:2015-07-15T15:20:00.000
set ARGS=%ARGS% /endDate:2015-07-15T17:30:00.000
set ARGS=%ARGS% /IDs:250
set ARGS=%ARGS% /values:10000,20000
.....
```

now I want to read it and overwrite it with new dates (1 day after current start and enddate). My code below works fine if I write it to a new file but doesn't work if I tried to overwrite it. Any idea about how to fix it?

```
WANTED = 19 #or however many characters you want after dates

with open('myfile.bat') as searchfile, open('mynewfile.bat', 'w') as outfile:


    for line in searchfile:
        left,sep,right = line.partition('startDate:')
        if sep: # True iff 'Figure' in line
            startdatestr = (right[:WANTED])
            startdate = datetime.strptime(startdatestr, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            newstartdate = startdate + timedelta(days=1)
            newstartdatestr = newstartdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            line = line.replace(startdatestr, newstartdatestr)  


        left,sep,right = line.partition('endDate:')
        if sep: # True iff 'Figure' in line
            enddatestr = (right[:WANTED])
            enddate = datetime.strptime(enddatestr, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            newenddate = enddate + timedelta(days=1)
            newenddatestr = newenddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            line = line.replace(enddatestr, newenddatestr)  
        outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are in the 'with open()' part, your file is still open, so you cannot overwrite it. Store the content and your modifications in variables, leave the 'with open()' part so that the file handle closes.

Then open the file for writing and output your data to it.